# Generic inheritance in java

Tags: java, c++, templates, generics

In c++ we can write:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base1
{
public: void test() { std::cout << "Base 1" << std::endl; }
};

class Base2
{
    public: void test() { std::cout << "Base 2" << std::endl; }
};

template<class T>
class Derived: public T
{

};

int main()
{
    Derived<Base1> d1;
    Derived<Base2> d2;
    d1.test();
    d2.test();
}
```

To get templated inheritance.

Can the same be done in java using generics?

Thanks.

Edit: Adding more info about my intentions

In my scenario I have two subclasses, Sprite and AnimatedSprite (which is a subclass of Sprite). The next step is a PhysicalSprite that adds physics to the sprites, but I want it to be able to inherit from both Sprite and AnimatedSprite.

Comment: +1, I didn't know C++ templates could do that! (This could be used for achieving effects like dynamic mixin composition in Scala :)

Comment: @missingfaktor: google for the CRTP pattern

Comment: @Armen: This is not an example of CRTP pattern. CRTP has a general structure `class A : B<A>`, which is not the case with OP's code.

Comment: @missingfaktor: I think Armen's point is that if you want mixins in C++, CRTP is the way to do it, rather than this. I have no idea whether CRTP actually mimics the Scala thing you're talking about, since "mixin" means different things to different people. But I don't think Armen was claiming that this is CRTP.

Comment: @missingfaktor As you said you didn't know C++ templates could do that, I supposed that you could have fun reading about the CRTP, which I do know is not very related to the OP's question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. C++'s templates are [much stronger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C%2B%2B#Templates_vs._Generics) than Java's generics. Generics in Java are only for ensuring proper typing during compile time and are not present in the generated bytecode - this is called [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Type_erasure).

> In my scenario I have two subclasses, Sprite and AnimatedSprite (which is a subclass of Sprite). The next step is a PhysicalSprite that adds physics to the sprites, but I want it to be able to inherit from both Sprite and AnimatedSprite.

Inheritance is not the only form of code reuse. This use case can be handled with other patterns as well, such as simple [decoration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). Consider something akin to the following:

```
interface Sprite { ... }
class StaticSprite implements Sprite { ... }
class AnimatedSprite implements Sprite { ... }

class PhysicalSprite implements Sprite, Physics {
    PhysicalSprite(Sprite inner) { ... }
    ...
}
```

PhysicalSprite would in this case delegate the Sprite parts to some Sprite instance provided in the constructor. It would then be free to add its own handling for the Physics part.

Comment: computationally and conceptually :)

Answer (score 1):

Alas, no.

Unlike C++, which can be thought to emit a different class definition for every instantiation of a template, all instantiations of a generic type share the same runtime class in Java, and therefore have the same method definitions. Generics (in Java) are  compile-time and not tracked at runtime.

Therefore, the Java Language Specification explictly [forbids](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1.4) to specify a type paramater as superclass or implemented interface:

> The optional extends clause in a normal class declaration specifies the direct superclass of the current class.
>
> *Super*: extends *ClassType*

where *ClassType* is a qualified or unqualified class name (with optional type arguments)

**Workarounds**

1. Use the decorator pattern if you don't need to override methods invoked by the super class.
2. Generate a dedicated subclass for each instantiation of the template. You can do so at runtime using, for instance, Javassist, or using source code transformations at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

No, not in exact same way. But if you tell us what exactly you want to do, I'm pretty sure there'll be some elegant way to do that. I just don't see any need for templates/generics in your example.
In particular, it looks like `Base1` and `Base2` might benefit from common interfaces with method `test`.

Comment: @monoceres Well, design patterns isn't my strong side, but it seems there're some suggestions already (and maybe soon some more experienced people than me will arrive to help).

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. Do you need [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)?